# Azure, SocketIO and NodeJS: how know on which port the server is listening

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

i have created a nodejs app and deployed on azure (as Web App). In many tutorial i have see that the port declaration must be:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
```

How can i see on which port the server is listening? If i tried to see the azure log i see the that the port is:

```
server listen on port: \\.\pipe\908cedb1-d2e6-4501-a34d-fa9396ef7417
```

I want know the port on which the server is listening because i want implement a socket io with standalone client (a console socket io client that connect to socket io server).

Which is the port on which the client must connect on the server?